# How can I connect database (mongoDB) to the component?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, mongodb, express

Im quite new here, I did login/register form and authentication following the tutorial but I don't know how can I connect mongoDB with the component. I was trying to follow the youtube tutorial about NodeJS + Express but I had a problem with useUnifiedTopology in /bin and couldn't make it work..

Here is the code snippet of auto-fill-text-field which I want to get data from database

https://codesandbox.io/s/auto-search-field-from-database-zcudn

Comment: Why would you need to connect to the database? I don't see you are creating your own endpoints here. Instead, you're fetching from jsonplaceholder.typecode. You're already getting the data from the fake rest api that you are using.

Comment: I need to connect to the database because its a MERN stack, I have created database which holds registered users and I need to get data from database to show them and assign them to the workplace

Comment: If you've set up your backend with express, there's a file called app.js and there you have to setup your mongoDB connection, just before the routes. After that, you just have to integrate your frontend with the backend.

Comment: Yeahh Im pretty sure I have something like that, not really in app.js but yeah.. What about that integrate frontend with backend? Could you explain that for me?